# Can a simple neural net learn the sin function applied to a summation of four numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, regression, trigonometry

I have a simple multi-layer perceptron with a single hidden layer and tanh activations in the hidden and output layers. As part of an assignment, I have created a data set with 1000 examples. Each input (`x_i`) is an array of four random numbers between -1.0 and +1.0. Each label (`y_i`) is produced as `sin(x_i[0] - x_i[1] + x_i[2] - x_i[3])`. My MLP takes in each of the 4 elements of `x_i` as input, and produces a single output. Is it possible for this single hidden layered MLP to learn to produce this summation of the four inputs, and then apply the sin function?

I trained the MLP using the first 80% of the data set, and tested it on the last 20% every 1,000 epochs, up to 50,000. Using the MSE loss function, the train and test losses are always relatively similar, but don't decrease a huge amount during the 50,000 training epochs, and were jumping up and down quite a bit. The loss values on the final epoch for training and testing were 0.01505 and 0.01504, respectively.

After these 50,000 training epochs, I then produced a data set of the same format, with new random numbers between -1.0 and +1.0. I then sorted this data by the `y` values, and made a prediction from the trained MLP for each. This resulted in the following plot:

[image]

Clearly, the MLP learns the general trend, but the exact values are extremely volatile. Is there any explanation as to why it cannot learn this function any better? There didn't seem to be much improvement from 10,000 epochs to 50,000. Is it due to having just a single hidden layer?

Answer (score 2):

If your training loss peaks during training despite an abundance of data samples, you can be (almost) certain that your model lacks the necessary **capacity** to tackle the problem. Representational capacity can be improved by increasing the width of your hidden layer(s), increasing the network depth or alternatively switching from a dense layer to either  recurrent or a convolutional layer with the same number of parameters. To make sure that lack of capacity is indeed your issue here, generate more data and see if the peak performance changes at all. If it doesn't, try either of the above techniques above and check whether your model can follow the pattern any better.

---

**Edit**: Posting some example results I got with a few different architectures. All results on test data after training on 1000 samples for 1500 epochs.

One hidden layer of shape 100:
[image: Single hidden]

One simple recurrent layer of shape 20:
[image: Single recurrent layer]

Two dense hidden layers of shapes (50,20):
[image: Two hidden layers]

Four hidden layers of shapes (32,32,16,16):
[image]